# CIFS mount keep return host is down even if it is not

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_network_folders) and I mount two folders using the following command in `/etc/fstab`

```
//192.168.1.227/folder1 /media/folder1 cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//192.168.1.227/folder2 /media/folder2 cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

First of all, the mounts are **working**. However, if I access the folder1(e.g. `ls`) while the remote is down, it throws "host is down" and keeps throwing even 
 the remote is up.(folder2 is on the **same** remote and reachable) If I do nothing while the remote is down, everything is fine.

For example,

```
folder1 & folder2 on Remote1
ls in /media/folder1 → Everything OK
ls in /media/folder2 → Everything OK
        ↓
Remote1 down
ls in /media/folder1 → "host is down"
        ↓
Remote1 up
ls in /media/folder1 → "host is down"
ls in /media/folder2 → Everything OK
        ↓
mount -a
ls in /media/folder1 → "host is down"
ls in /media/folder2 → Everything OK
        ↓
Reboot
ls in /media/folder1 → Everything OK
ls in /media/folder2 → Everything OK
```

This happens on both folder. I tried `mount -a` but it still throws "host is down". Only reboot can solve it.

How to make it stop throwing "host is down" after the remote is up again?

Comment: As I understand you, you expect the mounts to notice when the host is back online? Well, it will not. You can use the remount option in fstab but you still manually mount them again (mount -a) or you write a wrapper script.

Comment: @WillemK I do not except the mounts to notice when the host is back online. I expect it will actual check the mount is online or not when I run command instead of caching the fail result. Also, as I mentioned above `mount -a`  does not work. I don't know why but no error was thrown.

Comment: No, it only checks if the other side is online when you do the first mount. It will then register the mount(s) in /proc. See man mount for more details. As long as the mount is registered, any subsequent mount -a will do/show nothing. You must use `umount -a` and `mount -a` to force a refresh.

Comment: @WillemK Is there a way to make force refresh itself? The only way I can think of is use a cron to check it.

Comment: Indeed, cron would be the obvious choice. Be sure though you only do the umount/moun toggle after being sure the host was indeed down and up again. Next thing.... would it be a good idea to find out why the remote host goes down? Unless of course, it is a scheduled outage.

Comment: I schedule the remote to update and some service on my server will try to access it during outage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58773/discussion-between-willemk-and-joshua).